# Practices to detect tenant in multi-tenant applications

Tags: web-applications, multitenancy

I am wondering what are the best practices to build multi-tenant  applications, specifically ways to obtain tenant identifier or detect tenant. I am aware of domain based tenancy where domain tells you who is the tenant. In one of my applications where domain based approach is not an option, i am storing tenant id along with other details in auth cookie when user signed in and with every request i know who is tenant. I am wondering what are the other practices and possibly any pros/cons.

Comment: This is too broad to be answerable here.  Focus on your specific problem, establish some specific goals, tell us what those goals are, and we'll see if we can help you meet them.

Comment: @RobertHarvey I don't think it is that broad. I am interested in approaches, I can implement whatever. And I think my goal/question is clear enough too, "how one can detect tenant in a web application ?"

Comment: Approaches to what?  Store a TenantID in your User record.

Comment: No, "Practices to detect tenant in multi-tenant applications": one is (sub)domain based, one is to store tenant identifier in cookie, one is to store in db. What else are there ?

Comment: Which way works best for your particular application?

Comment: Question is not specific to my application, it is a general question. But in my application domain based is not an option, cookie based works fine. I am interested to know generally what are practices out there. I don't know how else i can explain it.

Comment: The problem is, we're not set up to provide a general overview, survey or tutorial of a particular topic or subject matter.  This is a Q&A site, it works best when you can make your question *specific.*

Comment: I am not asking for tutorial or conducting a survey, I am asking a best practices question on a specific topic. Looking at other questions in this platform I believe my question totally makes sense. Maybe it is you don't get the point. Also, who are "we" ? Is your profile used by few people ?

Comment: Have a look here: https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6758

Answer (score 0):

You could mail them an implant that they can install in their hand and plugin to their computer via usb.

Then you write a browser plugin to detect this USB device and validate the genetic code of your "tenant".

This eliminates the needs for passwords and is practically foolproof.

Comment: So all I've got to do is knock out one of the employees and hold their hand up to the sensor. I'm in. I feel like I saw something like this in a movie once...